# Camel not recognizing ?lock=false as valid

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I've got a camel route reading from a file and it's not deleting the .CamelLock file after the route finishes so I wanted to turn lock off. The documentation for Camel-File says that the attribute is "lock" yet when I do `<from uri="file:///data/in/?lock=false" />` I get:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to
>   resolve endpoint: file:///data/in/?lock=false due to: Failed to
>   resolve endpoint: file:///data/in/?lock=false due to: There are 1
>   parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the
>   parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the
>   endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{lock=false}]

Camel 2.11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file component documentation for Camel 2.x is here: http://camel.apache.org/file2
You most likely read the old Camel 1.x documentation at: http://camel.apache.org/file 
Notice on the top of the page, it says this is for Camel 1.x!

There is a readLock option which by default uses markerFile (and hence why you see those .camelLock files). You can turn this off by setting the readLock option to none, eg

```
readLock=none
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks for the correction. I'll keep an eye out for that in the future.

Answer (score -1):

try using `?readLock=false`

see https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/FileNoOpLockFileTest.java